# Объединение нескольких data frames по одним циклом + замена значений по критерию

Tags: r, rstudio

У меня имеется инвестиционный портфель ценный бумаг, пример ниже:

```
 portfolio <- data.frame(ISIN = c('ABC US Equity', 'DEF US Equity', 'GHI US Equity'),
         Buy.Date = c('22.10.2014', '02.05.2015', '07.08.2016'),
         Sale.Date = c('30.05.2015', '15.02.2016', '31.12.2017'),
         Buy.Price = c('107.1','101.3','97.8'),
         Sale.Price = c('85.69', '102.5', '100'),
         Position = c('200','250','300'))

 > portfolio
   ISIN           Buy.Date   Sale.Date Buy.Price Sale.Price Position
   ABC US Equity 22.10.2014 30.05.2015 107.1        85.69      200
   DEF US Equity 02.05.2015 15.02.2016 101.3        102.5      250
   GHI US Equity 07.08.2016 31.12.2017 97.8         100        300
```

Моя задача получить единую data.frame следующего вида:

```
> portfolio    
  ISIN           Buy.Date   Sale.Date Buy.Price Sale.Price Position
  ABC US Equity 22.10.2014 30.05.2015 107.1        85.69      200
  ABC US Equity 02.05.2015 30.05.2015 107.1        85.69      200
  DEF US Equity 02.05.2015 15.02.2016 101.3        102.5      250
  DEF US Equity 30.05.2015 15.02.2016 101.3        102.5      250
  DEF US Equity 07.08.2016 15.02.2016 101.3        102.5      250
  GHI US Equity 07.08.2016 31.12.2017 97.8         100        300
  GHI US Equity 15.02.2016 31.12.2017 97.8         100        300
```

Иными слова, это должен быть т.н. "снимок" позиций портфеля на каждую дату покупку (Buy.Date) и дату продажи (Sale.Date). Фактически это подразумевает объединение следующих data frames:

```
ISIN           Buy.Date   Sale.Date Buy.Price Sale.Price Position
ABC US Equity 22.10.2014 30.05.2015 107.1        85.69      200

ISIN           Buy.Date   Sale.Date Buy.Price Sale.Price Position
ABC US Equity 02.05.2015 30.05.2015 107.1        85.69      200
DEF US Equity 02.05.2015 15.02.2016 101.3        102.5      250

ISIN           Buy.Date   Sale.Date Buy.Price Sale.Price Position
DEF US Equity 30.05.2015 15.02.2016 101.3        102.5      250

ISIN           Buy.Date   Sale.Date Buy.Price Sale.Price Position
DEF US Equity 07.08.2016 15.02.2016 101.3        102.5      250
GHI US Equity 07.08.2016 31.12.2017 97.8         100        300

ISIN           Buy.Date   Sale.Date Buy.Price Sale.Price Position
GHI US Equity 15.02.2016 31.12.2017 97.8         100        300
```

Пока я только лишь создал два цикла, которые создают data frames на каждую уникальную дату покупки и продажи

```
for(i in unique(portfolio$Buy.Date)) {
  nam <- paste("portfolio", i, sep = ".")
  assign(nam, portfolio[portfolio$Buy.Date==i,])
}

for(j in unique(portfolio$Sale.Date)) {
     nam <- paste("portfolio", j, sep = ".")
     assign(nam, portfolio[portfolio$Buy.Date==i,])
}
```

Проблема пока состоит в объединении всех этих data frames (возможно, под одним циклом?) таким образом, чтобы это действительно отражало "снимки" портфеля в каждый отдельный момент времени, как я и показал выше. Возможно ли это сделать в R?

Заранее премного благодарен за любую помощь!

P.S. В портфеле есть позиции, которые еще не проданы на сегодняшнюю дату, именно поэтому есть дата 31.12.2017 в колонке Sale.Date , т.е. "последняя" data frame должна отображать Sale.Date = 31.12.2017.

Comment: Непонятно: DEF US Equity куплены 02.05.2015 и проданы 15.02.2016, как они могут быть в портфеле на момент 07.08.2016?

Answer (score 0):

Сложно понять из описания, что требуется. Попробую ответить.

- Есть несколько или одно портфолио
- Нужно составить одно портфолио, отсортированное по дате покупки
- Либо одно большое портфолио нужно разгруппировать по дате покупки

#### Код на R

```
# Экспорт первого портфолио
portfolio1 <- data.frame(ISIN = c('ABC US Equity', 'DEF US Equity', 'GHI US Equity'),
         Buy.Date = c('22.10.2014', '02.05.2015', '07.08.2016'),
         Sale.Date = c('30.05.2015', '15.02.2016', '31.12.2017'),
         Buy.Price = c('107.1', '101.3', '97.8'),
         Sale.Price = c('85.69', '102.5', '100'),
         Position = c('200', '250', '300'))

# Экспорт второго портфолио
portfolio2 <- data.frame(ISIN = c('ABC US Equity', 'DEF US Equity', 'GHI US Equity'),
         Buy.Date = c('22.10.2014', '02.05.2015', '17.08.2016'),
         Sale.Date = c('30.05.2015', '15.04.2016', '31.11.2017'),
         Buy.Price = c('117.1', '102.3', '94.8'),
         Sale.Price = c('82.69', '103.5', '105'),
         Position = c('100', '150', '200'))

# Объединение экспортируемых портфолио в одно портфолио
portfolio <- rbind(portfolio1, portfolio2)

# Сортируем портфолио по дате покупки
portfolio$Buy.Date <- as.Date(portfolio$Buy.Date, "%d.%m.%Y")
portfolio <- portfolio[with(portfolio, order(Buy.Date)),]

# Выводим портфолио на консоль
portfolio
#            ISIN   Buy.Date  Sale.Date Buy.Price Sale.Price Position
# 1 ABC US Equity 2014-10-22 30.05.2015     107.1      85.69      200
# 4 ABC US Equity 2014-10-22 30.05.2015     117.1      82.69      100
# 2 DEF US Equity 2015-05-02 15.02.2016     101.3      102.5      250
# 5 DEF US Equity 2015-05-02 15.04.2016     102.3      103.5      150
# 3 GHI US Equity 2016-08-07 31.12.2017      97.8        100      300
# 6 GHI US Equity 2016-08-17 31.11.2017      94.8        105      200

# Группируем портфолио по дате покупки
# На выходе получается список с data.frame (с портфолио с одинаковыми датами покупки)   

portfolio.list <- split(portfolio, portfolio$Buy.Date)

# Вывод листа на консоль
portfolio.list
# $`2014-10-22`
#            ISIN   Buy.Date  Sale.Date Buy.Price Sale.Price Position
# 1 ABC US Equity 2014-10-22 30.05.2015     107.1      85.69      200
# 4 ABC US Equity 2014-10-22 30.05.2015     117.1      82.69      100
# 
# $`2015-05-02`
#            ISIN   Buy.Date  Sale.Date Buy.Price Sale.Price Position
# 2 DEF US Equity 2015-05-02 15.02.2016     101.3      102.5      250
# 5 DEF US Equity 2015-05-02 15.04.2016     102.3      103.5      150
# 
# $`2016-08-07`
#            ISIN   Buy.Date  Sale.Date Buy.Price Sale.Price Position
# 3 GHI US Equity 2016-08-07 31.12.2017      97.8        100      300
# 
# $`2016-08-17`
#            ISIN   Buy.Date  Sale.Date Buy.Price Sale.Price Position
# 6 GHI US Equity 2016-08-17 31.11.2017      94.8        105      200
```